# Best solution to remove all keys excluded custom-user keys in Redis?

Tags: database, nosql, redis

In Redis i can remove keys by mask on backend. Implemented mask not allow to remove the necessary keys.

So, the question in subject.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear? Explain more in detail what you want to do.

Comment: Add your queries code also. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say you have the following keys in Redis:

- A:mx:a
- A:web:a
- A:web:d
- B:mx:a
- A:web:d
- B:web:d
- B:web:d:o
- C:mx:a
- D:mx:a
- B:web:d:o

If you want to remove all keys that contains *web:d* do:

```
redis-cli KEYS "*web:d*" | xargs redis-cli DEL
```

If you want to remove all keys that ending with "d" do:

```
redis-cli KEYS "*:d" | xargs redis-cli DEL
```

If you want to remove all keys based on a regexp (of course we could use B:mx:web as the KEYS pattern):

```
redis-cli KEYS "*:mx:*" | grep "B:mx:web" | xargs redis-cli DEL
```